# Can networkx find girth of a graph?

Tags: graph, networkx, girth

Is there a way for NetworkX to give you the girth of a graph?

I know i can do min([len(c) for c in nx.simple_cycles(G)]) but for large, highly connected graphs this is time consuming. They list a girth function in their documentation but when I try and use it it says "AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'girth'".

Seems crazy they wouldn't have this function implemented.

Thanks

Comment: It should be implemented: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.girth.html